# How to safely store information about in app purchases / Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I'm looking for some technical advice how to solve this:

How to safely store information about in app purchases into device (Unity3D). The reason is that I won't force the user every time when he starts the game to check if he has the premium staff. So I want to save information about purchase into PlayerPrefs, but in some hashed way to protect this information. Any advice or experience?

Talking about both platforms (Android and iOS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I found that the best approach here is to use the device ID as part of hashed information (for some protection against copying the raw file into other device).

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right path. Store purchases as Hashed `ints` using [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html).

Use your favorite Hashing algorithm. I would create a class to delegate this hashing and storing task.

Comment: Hi @FunctionR, after some digging and some advices I guess the best approach here is to use here device ID as part of hashed information (for some protection against copying the raw file into other device)